# Jquery .append() problem with modal view

Tags: jquery, append, modal-view

I created simple modal view photo gallery that gets picture where user clicked and shows it in modal view.It works but problem if user clicked 2 or 5 times while model view opens then it shows 2 or 5 the same images in modal view. I used like

`$('.popup_block').find('div#userPhoto').append($theImage.clone());`

How can I limit it ?

Here is my function that catch user click action. Loading function that creates modal view and so on.And it takes 2-3 seccond

```
$(this).bind('click',function(){
var $this=$(this);

loading($this);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) which appends content, use [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) first or [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) which replaces it:

```
$('.popup_block').find('div#userPhoto').html($theImage.clone());
```

For those doing a double take, this isn't what it looks like, [what's *really* happening with `.html()` above is a shortcut for this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/manipulation.js#L262):

```
$('.popup_block').find('div#userPhoto').empty().append($theImage.clone());
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `unbind`?

Put an `unbind` inside the `loading()` function so that successive clicks don't invoke the process. -

```
$("#element").unbind('click');
```

Where `#element` is the identifier of the element on which you are calling the `bind()`